# SQL - Change Column A value when Column B is less than a certain value

Tags: sql

Using sql query on a DB and importing information into another DB. So, I want to change the value of a column if the date in Column B is less than a certain value.

e.g.- If Column B is less than `01/01/2015` then column `A = 0`, otherwise leave A alone.

I have tried a few variations my latest incarnation is which obviously doesn't work.

```
CASE 
 WHEN ColB <" + Constants.StartOfYear.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + @" 
 THEN ColA = 0
END
```

I use lots of other `CASE` statement and have already selected all my columns from the table

Comment: what does this have to do with C#?

Comment: Dmitry's answer had a lot of C# in it. but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I uderstand you right, all you want is *update* some values.
If it's your case, you can use *UPDATE DML*:

```
  String sql = 
    @"update MyTable
         set ColA = 0
       where ColB < @prm_ColB"; // '@' - For MS SQL, ':' for Oracle etc.
```

then assign value to `prm_ColB` and execute it like that:

```
  // Assuming that you're working with MS SQL
  using (var con = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString)) {
    con.Connect();

    using (var q = new SqlCommand(con)) {
      q.CommandText = sql;

      // Put actual parameter value here
      q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_ColB", new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1));

      q.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } 
  }
```

give your RDBMS an actual `DateTime` value via binding variable (`@prm_ColB`) do not try converting the date into `string` for hardcoding.